# sbt: copy resources to classpath in multi project build

Tags: sbt, unmanagedresources

I have a sbt project with following structure:

```
project
|
|-- file.json
|-- <serverProject>
|-- <clientProject>
```

`project` aggregates both `serverProject` and `clientProject`. Starting sbt and compiling works fine.

When running or packaging `serverProject` I want `file.json` to end up at the classpath of `serverProject`.

I added `file.json` to the `unmanagedResources in (Compile)` for `serverProject` but I get following error when trying to run / package:

```
[info] Done packaging.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate mappings:
    project/serverProject/target/scala-2.11/classes/file.json
from
    file.json
        project/serverProject/file.json
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.Sync$.noDuplicateTargets(Sync.scala:67)
    ...
```

It looks like sbt finds both the project root directory and serverProject directory as candidates for `file.json` after which it fails.

How to get around this error?

Thanks for reading and helping out!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my issue! When adding following setting to serverProject it works as expected:

```
unmanagedResources in (Compile) ++= Seq(file(baseDirectory.value.getParentFile.getAbsolutePath + "/file.json"))
```